# Implementing Contact Form Like functionality to send Emails from iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

In my app the functionality required is similar to "contact form". I want that user should be able to send email to me using that contact form.

**Now the form should contain textFields for Subject and Message Body but the Recipient Email Address should be pre-fixed and should not be shown.As I dont want to disclose my email id to all users.**

What should i do?

How to prepare such contact form like functionality using which users can send email?

Please Give Your Suggestions.

Your Suggestions are most welcome.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to create a POST request with the values of your form, and then send it to a server of your own, that will itself send the mail for you. Otherwise, you should embed an SMTP client in your code, and I don't know if there are any available for iOS (I don't mean there aren't, it's just I don't know any :)

I suggest you take a look to [the ASIFormDataRequest class](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#sending_a_form_post_with_ASIFormDataRequest) in the ASIHTTPRequest framework, as it will simplify your life for doing such a thing.